# How to upgrade an HTTP/3 connection into WebSocket?

Tags: websocket, quic, http3

Is HTTP/3 compatible with WebSocket?
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

While there exist [RFC 8441](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8441) that specifies how to bootstrap WebSocket over HTTP/2, there is not yet such RFC (in final form) for HTTP/3.

However, given that HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 are quite similar (at the HTTP/x framing layer), this is in the work at this draft RFC: https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-hamilton-httpbis-h3-websockets-00.html.

I expect browsers and libraries to implement this draft RFC in the following months, like it happened for RFC 8441.

Currently, a browser will either open a separate WebSocket connection, or use an existing HTTP/2 connection as specified by RFC 8441.